# How to parse and populate the value from one field into an another in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple form with two input fields. I would like to take the text from one field and snip the first part and replace it with some other text and populate it into the second field dynamically. I was able to achieve the getting part from the field with ease but I am not sure how to snip the value on keyup. The following is the code:
Component HTML

```
<div class="labels">Real Name</div> 
<div class="lbl">
     <input #realName type="text" [(ngModel)]="actualName" (keyup)="trigger()">
 </div>
 <div class="labels">Cyber Name</div>
 <div class="lbl">
     <input #cybName type="text"[(ngModel)]="cyberName"> 
  </div>
```

Component TS

```
@ViewChild('realName') realName: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('cybName') cybName: ElementRef;

trigger() {
  this.cybName.nativeElement.value = this.realName.nativeElement.value;
}
```

On every keyup, I am setting the value of the cybName with the realName. But, I would like to snip the first 4 characters of the realName and replace it with droid and the remaining characters of the realName i.e., if the typed in real Name was "Alexys", I would like to make it "droidys".

I am sure I shouldn't be doing it with keyup but I am not sure what else to use for this situation. Could anyone help me with it. Thank you.

Comment: Try using reactive forms instead. Once you do that you can use the value changes observable and with that you could use a filter method to make sure you snip only after the first 4 characters have been typed.

Comment: Will post an answer as soon as I get to a laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution that I think will solve your issue:

Changes in html:

```
<input #realName type="text" [ngModel]="actualName" (ngModelChange)="trigger($event)">
```

Changes in ts:

```
trigger(newActualName) {
  this.actualName = newActualName;
  this.cyberName = `Droid${event.substring(4)}`;
}
```

When you update the model (`actualName` and `cyberName`) it will also update the input with the new values.

Also: Angular warns against using the `ElementRef` and accessing the DOM directly. See [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) for more info

Comment: I really like this answer. But I am not why not just keep the `[(ngModel)]` as two way binding?

Comment: `[(ngModel)]=actualName` is shorthand for `[ngModel]="actualName" (ngModelChange)="actualName = $event"`. I just wanted to show that you could also use the `ngModelChange`-event to do the stuff you wanted to do in the `keyup`-event. But that is also perfectly fine.

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the splice to cut up your input. I am also assuming the following use cases

"AAAAAA" -> "droidAA"

"AAAA" -> "droid"

"AA" -> "AA"

```
const strLength = this.realName.nativeElement.value && this.realName.nativeElement.value.toString().length;

if (strLength >= 4) {
    this.cybName.nativeElement.value = 'droid' + this.realName.nativeElement.value.toString().splice(4, strLength);
} else {
    this.cybName.nativeElement.value = this.realName.nativeElement.value;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't have to use `nativeElement`. You should be able to use the variables themselves.

```
if (this.actualName && this.acutualName.length >= 4) {
    this.cyberName = 'droid' + this.actualName.splice(4, this.acutualName.length);
} else {
    this.cyberName = this.actualName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to append the substr:

```
let cyberName = 'droid';
let realName = 'Alexys';
let cyberDroidName = `${cyberName}${realName.substring(4)}`;
console.log(cyberDroidName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<div class="labels">Real Name</div> 
<div class="lbl">
     <input #realName type="text" [(ngModel)]="actualName">
 </div>
 <div class="labels">Cyber Name</div>
 <div class="lbl">
     <input #cybName type="text"[ngModel]="'droid' + actualName.substring(4)"> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by all the answers there are many ways to skin this Cat. If it were me, I would use a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) to achieve this. As shown in this [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-weh2ls).

You can create a pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'robotNamePipe'})
export class RobotNamePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent: string): string {

  // Run your logic in here

    return `${value} - Anyhting you want!`;
  }
}
```

... and then in your HTML use it like this:

```
<div class="labels">Real Name</div> 
<div class="lbl">
     <input #realName type="text" [(ngModel)]="actualName">
 </div>
 <div class="labels">Cyber Name</div>

<p>Robot name: {{realName.value | robotNamePipe}}</p>
```

Because really, you probably don't want people to be able to edit the generated droid name anyway - do you?